# How to debug why my pods are pending in GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'#m trying to get a pod running on GCE.  The pod has an init container, and is created by me applying a manifest with a deployment that creates 1 replica of the pod.

When I look at my workloads on the cloud console, I can see that under 'Active revisions' my deployment is in the state of 'Pods are pending', and under 'Managed pods', the status is 'PodsInitializing'.

The container logs are empty, and the audit logs contain a single entry for the creation of the deployment.

My pods seem to be stuck in the above state, and I'm not really sure why.  How do I go about debugging that?

Edit:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=my-namespace
```

Outputs:

```
NAME                        READY     STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
my-pod-v77jm                0/1       Init:0/1   0          55m
```

But when I run:

```
kubectl describe pod my-pod-v77jm
```

I get

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "my-pod-v77jm" not found
```

Comment: Do you have access to the kube api ? Can you use `kubectl` ?

Comment: Yes, I've just done a 'Kubectl get pods --namespace=mynamespace'.  Looks like the pod is in the init phase.  It must just be taking longer than what I expected.  Is there any way to view to logs for the init container?

Comment: @Andy yes. kubectl logs <pod-name> -c <container-name>

Comment: Thanks, I've added an edit, but in short, my pod's name shows up when I search for all pods in my namespace, the pod shows up, but when I try to get the logs or describe the pod, it can't be found.

Comment: If adding `--namespace=my-namespace` to your command to get pods is working, make sure you add that to your other kubectl commands to describe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to kube-api via `kubectl`:

Use `describe` see details about the pod and containers

```
kubectl describe myPod --namespace mynamespace
```

To view container logs (including init containers)

```
kubectl logs myPod --namespace mynamespace -c initContainerName
```

You can get more information about pod statuses and how to debug init containers [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/#getting-details-about-init-containers)

Comment: I've just edited my post, I've ran a describe, and although the pod is showing in GCE, and when I search for pods in my namespace, it cannot be found when I try to describe it.

Comment: Do you see the same when you describe any other pod ? or this is the only one 
? are you running a kubeadm set up ?

Comment: It's the only pod I'm running.  I've managed to get a better idea of what's going on by called 'kubectl describe pods --namespace=my-namespace", which showed me that the volumes weren't being mounted to my pod.  I'm still trying to fix misc issues, but I still can't use kubectl to view my pod directly.

Comment: just to make sure, you did add the namespace flag while trying to describe the pod only right ?

Comment: I believe the proper way to describe is kubectl describe pods [podname] --namespace [namespacename]